# SQL query to change column names to single column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, unpivot, lateral-join

I'm using SQL Server. Not sure what version, but it's still supported.
I have a table that has 3 columns that I'm interested in. I need to change the column names in a 'hardware' column with the counts for each. Right now I have the following:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(a.EAMacBook13) AS 'MacBook13', 
    COUNT(a.EAMacBook16) AS 'MacBook16', 
    COUNT(a.EAStandLaptop) AS 'StandLaptop' 
FROM 
    Employee AS e, EmpAttributes AS a 
WHERE 
    a.EAEmpID = e.EmpID AND e.EmpProjID = 1
```

[image]

where instead I need something like:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Find out the **version** of your SQL Server by running `SELECT @@VERSION` in SSMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a simple union all:

```
SELECT 'MacBook13' "Hardware", Count(a.EAMacBook13) "Count"
FROM Employee as e, EmpAttributes as a WHERE a.EAEmpID = e.EmpID and e.EmpProjID = 1
union all 
SELECT 'MacBook16' "Hardware", Count(a.EAMacBook16)  "Count"
FROM Employee as e, EmpAttributes as a WHERE a.EAEmpID = e.EmpID and e.EmpProjID = 1
union all 
SELECT 'StandLaptop' "Hardware", Count(a.EAStandLaptop)  "Count"
FROM Employee as e, EmpAttributes as a WHERE a.EAEmpID = e.EmpID and e.EmpProjID = 1
```

Depending on your RDBMS, you might have access to UNPIVOT which would make this less writing.

You could also use a CTE so that (if your RDBMS supports materializing them) you do less work:

```
with cte as (
  SELECT Count(a.EAMacBook13) as EAMacBook13, Count(a.EAMacBook16) as EAMacBook16, Count(a.EAStandLaptop) as EAStandLaptop
  FROM Employee as e, EmpAttributes as a WHERE a.EAEmpID = e.EmpID and e.EmpProjID = 1
)
SELECT 'MacBook13' "Hardware", EAMacBook13 "Count"
FROM  cte
union all 
SELECT 'MacBook16' "Hardware", MacBook16 "Count"
FROM cte
union all 
SELECT 'StandLaptop' "Hardware", StandLaptop "Count"
FROM cte
```

You will have to list out the possible Hardware values unless you use some degree of dynamic SQL.

Comment: You're missing a union all for the third value but this works exactly for what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The base idea is to unpivot and count. If your database supports lateral joins (aka `cross apply`) and `values()` you can do:

```
select x.hardware, count(x.val) cnt
from employee as e
inner join empattributes as ea on ea.eaempid = e.empid 
cross join lateral (values 
    ('EAMacBook13', ea.EAMacBook13), 
    ('EAMacBook16', ea.EAMacBook16), 
    ('EAStandLaptop', ea.EAStandLaptop)
) x(hardware, val)
where e.empprojid = 1
group by x.hardware
```

There are different syntaxes available for lateral joins, depending on your database. Some databases use `cross apply` instead of `cross join lateral`.

`values()` is also not supported everywhere. In Oracle, for example, you would phrase the lateral join as:

```
cross apply (
    select 'EAMacBook13' as hardware, EAMacBook13 as val from dual
    union all select 'EAMacBook16', EAMacBook16 from dual
    union all select 'EAStandLaptop', EAStandLaptop from dual
) x(hardware)
```

If none of that is available, then we can fallback on `union all`:

```
select x.hardware, count(x.val) cnt
from employee as e
inner join (
    select eaempid, 'EAMacBook13' as hardware, EAMacBook13 as value from empattributes 
    union all select eaempid, 'EAMacBook16', EAMacBook16 from empattributes 
    union all select eaempid, 'EAStandLaptop', EAStandLaptop from empattributes 
) x on x.eaempid = e.empid 
where e.empprojid = 1
group by x.hardware
```

Comment: @JimBedson: I see that you tagged your question SQL Server now. In this database, you can use the first query - just replace `cross join lateral` with `cross apply`. This is more efficient than `union all` in the answer your accepted, since it scans the table only once.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using Dynamic Unpivot. First create a table with the current query :

```
SELECT a.EAMacBook13, a.EAMacBook16, a.EAStandLaptop
  INTO tab
  FROM Employee AS e 
  JOIN EmpAttributes AS a 
    ON a.EAEmpID = e.EmpID
 WHERE e.EmpProjID = 1
```

and then use `information_schema.columns` :

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET  @query = 
    (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('SELECT ''',SUBSTRING(column_name,3,LEN(column_name)),''' AS Hardware, 
            COUNT(',column_name,') AS Count FROM tab '),' UNION ALL ')
       FROM information_schema.columns
      WHERE table_name = 'tab');

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6fd7289e852fa3dff8dd9d05da8f87cf)</kbd>